# Highcharts loses it's dateRange values after refresh on IE<=9 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, typescript

```
var newCurrent = that.getIndexForCounter(that.currentPCData.CounterID, that.currentPCData.NetworkID);
                            if (currentIndex == newCurrent) {
                                $.each(model.Data, (j, point) => {
                                    if (!_.isNumber(j)) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    highChartInstance.series[0].addPoint(point, false, true);
                                });
                                highChartInstance.redraw();
                            }
                            that.currentPCData = that.allPCModels[newCurrent];
```

I use this code to refresh my Highcharts chart and the problem appearts when it's first refreshed. 1 minute dateRange and 1 day dateRange work just fine, but 1 hour and 2 hours dateRanges seem to be broken and they show a much smaller time interval. The biggest problem is that this chart works perfectly fine in Firefox and in newer versions of Internet Explorer. Buttons for selecting dateRange have their type set on 'minute' and their count to '60'

Comment: How about creating simple demo with random data in jsFiddle? It's hard to guess what may be wrong.

Comment: Instead of going by Java api, use javascript it is more simpler and you can change data runtime

Answer (score 0):

It was solved using moment.js to parse Date values. For some reason default date parsing didn't work in Chrome

Comment: Its based on locale settings